Collaboration Diagrams (communication)
I have a big project on software engineering and I have to do some communication diagrams. The only thing I dont know how to draw the if then statements. Can someone help?
I searched on Youtube but the people explaining the diagrams only used simple examples without if then statements

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is a very broad question. What about buying an UML book, for example "The UML user guide" that goes in detail in each kind of diagram and explain how and when to use all its subtle features ?

Communication diagrams don't show if/then but only what really happens in a scenario, so the if then already decided. Like SD they are a snapshot of a scenario.
If you want to show if/then you need to go back to Activity diagrams.

I think OP refers to the numbering scheme of the messages, where letters are used when there are alternative paths....

@Christophe Maybe. Or maybe not. As long as the question is that vague...
